# Why not find a resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm uploading images:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PlaceViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~");
        string imagesPath = serverPath + "Content\\Uploads\\";
        string thumbPath = imagesPath + "Thumb\\";
        string fullPath = imagesPath + "Full\\";
        ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(thumbPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 100, true);
        ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(fullPath, fileName, model.ImageUploaded.InputStream, 600, true);

        model.Image = fileName;

        var place = new Place();
        model.ConvertToData(place);

        _placeRepository.Add(place);
        _placeRepository.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

File uploads and exist physical in disk

I'm calling image from html:

```
<img height="100px" src="/Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg" width="100px"/>
```

But I don't see this image.

If I call `localhost:23354/Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg` I have error:

> The resource cannot be found.   Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:
>   /Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is content at the root of your url?  You are requesting the image from /content, but when you uploaded it you uploaded it to ~/content/...  Are they they same location?

Comment: Why are there two down votes on this question?

Comment: I agree with Brettski. It's a perfectly valid question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loosers.

images saved in `ImageModel.ResizeAndSave` and append name extension '.jpg'

```
newImage.Save(savePath + fileName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

it turns out that the file is filename.jpg.jpeg

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in IIS in a virtual directory you should specify the virtual directory upfront. You should never hardcode urls in your views. Always use helpers:

```
<img height="100px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg")" width="100px"/>
```

Now when you are running locally without virtual directory the helper will generate:

```
/Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg
```

And when you upload your application in IIS inside a virtual directory the helper will generate the correct url once again:

```
/AppName/Content/Uploads/Thumb/833c4384-884d-4250-982c-d5df0fa875ef.jpg
```

So as you can see, you should never hardcode urls. Same stands for urls in your javascript files. Always use helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Still, you should use helpers as shown in my answer, otherwise your code will break when you deploy in IIS.